# Big tables on twocolumn page

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column

here's my problem.
I've a twocolumn environment and I write with `tabu` tables. I'm asking myself if it's possible to get them on multiple column, something like this

```
blah blah blah blah ||  |                 |
blah blah blah blah ||  |      TABLE      |
blah blah blah blah ||  |                 |
blah blah blah blah ||  |_________________|
blah blah blah blah ||  blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah ||  blah blah blah blah
 _________________  ||  blah blah blah blah
|                 | ||  blah blah blah blah
|      TABLE      | ||  blah blah blah blah
|                 | ||  blah blah blah blah
```

To get more complicated: my table environment contains **4 subtable** (loaded with `subcaption` package).

If it's possible, I prefer to keep `tabu` tables.

Thank you in advance, as always!

Alberto

EDIT: has rightly requested by users, I post a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,twosize]{extbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}

\newcommand\TheParagraphIUse{
    \subsection{The subsection}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{table}[h]\tabulinesep=2pt
    \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
            \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
            1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
            2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
            3   &   The number 3.   \\
            4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
            5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
            6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
    \end{subtable}  \vspace{3pt}

    \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
            \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
            1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
            2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
            3   &   The number 3.   \\
            4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
            5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
            6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
    \end{subtable}  \vspace{3pt}

    \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
            \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
            1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
            2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
            3   &   The number 3.   \\
            4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
            5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
            6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
    \end{subtable}  \vspace{3pt}

    \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
            \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
            1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
            2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
            3   &   The number 3.   \\
            4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
            5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
            6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
    \end{subtable}
    \end{table} 
\lipsum[1]
}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\TheParagraphIUse

\TheParagraphIUse

\TheParagraphIUse

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a MWE?! Please, make a compilable working MWE not just bla bla bla.

Comment: You don't have to use your real text, make up some little story about Walter Wombat and his friend Carl Capybara. Or use packages like `lipsum` or `blindtext` that provide some test text consisting of real words. But a series of *Blah* is not only boring and uncreative, but gives some serious problems with line breaks and greyness of text.

Comment: "I'm asking myself if it's possible to get them on multiple column[s]..." Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Can only be given if you provide a lot more information about your document setup (document class? width of text block? width of columns?) and the structure of your tables.

Comment: I've edited adding a MWE... shall I have to bump this?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is absolutely no caption in your example, it doesn't matter what you do. You don't have to use the `table` environment or the `subcaption` environment.

Nevertheless, i used captions to show that it is possible to split the tables and continue numbering. A bit of manual intervention will be needed though.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,twocolumn]{extbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}

\newcommand\TheParagraphIUse{
    \subsection{The subsection}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{table}\tabulinesep=2pt
        \caption{The first tables}
        \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
            \caption{No Wombat here}
            \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
                \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
                1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
                2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
                3   &   The number 3.   \\
                4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
                5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
                6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
        \end{subtable}  \vspace{3pt}

        \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
            \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
                \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
                1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
                2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
                3   &   The number 3.   \\
                4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
                5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
                6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
        \end{subtable}  \vspace{3pt}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}
        \ContinuedFloat
        \caption{The rest of the tables}
        \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
            \caption{My hovercraft is full of eels.}
            \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
                \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
                1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
                2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
                3   &   The number 3.   \\
                4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
                5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
                6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
        \end{subtable}  \vspace{3pt}

        \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}\small\centering\sffamily
            \rowcolors{2}{white}{green}
            \begin{tabu}{X[0.1pc] X[2pl]}
                \rowfont{\bfseries}no   &   Text    \\
                1   &   Here's some text.                   \\
                2   & It could be bigger than 1 line, like in this case in which the text describe Carl the Capybara.   \\
                3   &   The number 3.   \\
                4   & Four is an "a" on 133t sp33ch.    \\
                5   & All the multiple of 5 are numbers that end with 5 or 0.   \\
                6   &   The number of the beast.
            \end{tabu}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{table} 
    \lipsum[1]
}

\begin{document}

\TheParagraphIUse

\TheParagraphIUse

\TheParagraphIUse

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you!
But I still need help. Without `subcaption` I have very flexible space between tables, and I need they can stay with the most constanst distance possible. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want full control of the table positioning (meaning doing stuff by hand) you just avoid using captions and especially the `table` environment. It is specially placing the table boxes (and a bit of its content) for you.