# How can I distribute subfigures across a two column document?

Tags: subfloats, two-column, subcaption

I am using two-column mode and would like to distribute a group of figures across the two columns, but so that all figures have subcaptions (a,b,c,d,e,etc) and one main caption and figure number.

**I do not want a figure spanning the two columns**, but the equivalent of placing multiple figures one after another, except that they are part of the same "figure group". i.e. **a group of subfigures, capable of breaking across columns if its vertical size is too big for the page**.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Totam molestias commodi rerum reprehenderit. Rerum omnis occaecati est minus consectetur in ex repellendus. Nobis est doloribus aut nobis iste quidem.

Laboriosam et eveniet sint est cum adipisci et. Eum quaerat rerum voluptatem. Molestiae quo amet tempore saepe consequatur. Sit officia enim non facere ratione. Et porro sint saepe. Qui officia mollitia soluta veniam nostrum.

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Common caption}
\end{figure}

Totam molestias commodi rerum reprehenderit. Rerum omnis occaecati est minus consectetur in ex repellendus. Nobis est doloribus aut nobis iste quidem.

Laboriosam et eveniet sint est cum adipisci et. Eum quaerat rerum voluptatem. Molestiae quo amet tempore saepe consequatur. Sit officia enim non facere ratione. Et porro sint saepe. Qui officia mollitia soluta veniam nostrum.

\clearpage{}

Totam molestias commodi rerum reprehenderit. Rerum omnis occaecati est minus consectetur in ex repellendus. Nobis est doloribus aut nobis iste quidem.

Laboriosam et eveniet sint est cum adipisci et. Eum quaerat rerum voluptatem. Molestiae quo amet tempore saepe consequatur. Sit officia enim non facere ratione. Et porro sint saepe. Qui officia mollitia soluta veniam nostrum.

\begin{figure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example}
    \caption{a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example}
    \caption{b}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example}
    \caption{c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example}
    \caption{d}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example}
    \caption{e}
\end{figure}

Sequi non iure tempore consectetur et quam. Dolorem enim non ratione qui. Non molestiae aspernatur doloremque dolores ullam fugit nostrum. Qui perferendis vero nesciunt quo voluptates natus possimus pariatur. Nihil dolore veritatis reprehenderit. Odio reiciendis et et tempore aliquam enim.

Ex aut eveniet quae doloremque in recusandae. Cumque minima consequatur excepturi nihil optio modi et pariatur. Adipisci velit cupiditate non delectus similique officiis cum. Perferendis expedita non voluptatibus. Et nihil pariatur eius. Possimus iusto vitae nulla quia.

Distinctio voluptates omnis beatae rem itaque et itaque maxime. Qui minima qui sint sit harum facilis et et. Id fuga veritatis eos labore vero voluptatem iusto rerum. Quis natus excepturi harum tenetur beatae reiciendis.

\end{document}
```

In the first case, the problem is that the figure is too long for one column.
In the second case, each figure gets its own figure number.

How can I break a group of subfigures across columns?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326752/big-tables-on-twocolumn-page/333183#333183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into the `\ContinuedFloat` directive of the `caption` package. In the following example, the first three subfloats fit at the bottom of the first column, while the remaining four subfloats are placed at the top of the following column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

Totam molestias commodi rerum reprehenderit. Rerum omnis occaecati est minus consectetur in ex repellendus. Nobis est doloribus aut nobis iste quidem.

Laboriosam et eveniet sint est cum adipisci et. Eum quaerat rerum voluptatem. Molestiae quo amet tempore saepe consequatur. Sit officia enim non facere ratione. Et porro sint saepe. Qui officia mollitia soluta veniam nostrum.

\begin{figure}[b!]
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\ContinuedFloat
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Common caption}
\end{figure}

Totam molestias commodi rerum reprehenderit. Rerum omnis occaecati est minus consectetur in ex repellendus. Nobis est doloribus aut nobis iste quidem.

Laboriosam et eveniet sint est cum adipisci et. Eum quaerat rerum voluptatem. Molestiae quo amet tempore saepe consequatur. Sit officia enim non facere ratione. Et porro sint saepe.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It requires some manual splitting and positioning, but it does what I want. :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption,multicol}

\begin{document}

Totam molestias commodi rerum reprehenderit. Rerum omnis occaecati est minus consectetur in ex repellendus. Nobis est doloribus aut nobis iste quidem.

Laboriosam et eveniet sint est cum adipisci et. Eum quaerat rerum voluptatem. Molestiae quo amet tempore saepe consequatur. Sit officia enim non facere ratione. Et porro sint saepe. Qui officia mollitia soluta veniam nostrum.

\begin{figure*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{multicols}
    \caption{Common caption}
\end{figure*}

Totam molestias commodi rerum reprehenderit. Rerum omnis occaecati est minus consectetur in ex repellendus. Nobis est doloribus aut nobis iste quidem.

Laboriosam et eveniet sint est cum adipisci et. Eum quaerat rerum voluptatem. Molestiae quo amet tempore saepe consequatur. Sit officia enim non facere ratione. Et porro sint saepe. Qui officia mollitia soluta veniam nostrum.


Sequi non iure tempore consectetur et quam. Dolorem enim non ratione qui. Non molestiae aspernatur doloremque dolores ullam fugit nostrum. Qui perferendis vero nesciunt quo voluptates natus possimus pariatur. Nihil dolore veritatis reprehenderit. Odio reiciendis et et tempore aliquam enim.

Ex aut eveniet quae doloremque in recusandae. Cumque minima consequatur excepturi nihil optio modi et pariatur. Adipisci velit cupiditate non delectus similique officiis cum. Perferendis expedita non voluptatibus. Et nihil pariatur eius. Possimus iusto vitae nulla quia.

Distinctio voluptates omnis beatae rem itaque et itaque maxime. Qui minima qui sint sit harum facilis et et. Id fuga veritatis eos labore vero voluptatem iusto rerum. Quis natus excepturi harum tenetur beatae reiciendis.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but by splitting the figure across column, I waste space in which I could fit text (page limit in journal). So in your example, I would like the caption to not span two columns and be under (g), with the possibility of adding text under figure (g). I tried the caption package and caption*{}, which almost solves my problem, but then I have to fight with float positioning and potentially reset figure numbering and other ugly things like that. :/

Comment: you can put the caption inside the multicol, then since it balances the space wasted is limited, otherwise it is hard to  guess what you want really, just have a sequence of `figure` and just have a `\caption` in the last?